# Random Number In C Independent Of Time

Tags: c

Is there a way to generate random numbers in c language independent of time.
The idea is that I want to generate an array of random numbers at a time,but since rand() method depends on time,all the values in the array are generated similarly.

Comment: What do you mean by that "`rand()` depends on time"?

Comment: If you edit to explain more of what you're doing, you night shake off some of those downvotes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`rand()` doesn't depend on time. People typically seed their pseudo-random number generator *using* the current time (through the [`srand()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/srand) function), but they don't have to. You can just pass whatever number you want to `srand()`.

If your random numbers aren't of a high enough quality for your purposes (libc's `rand` is notorious for its inadequacy), you should look at other sources of randomness. On most operating systems, you can get high-quality random data just by reading from [`/dev/random`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) (or `/dev/urandom`), and the Windows API provides [`CryptGenRandom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There are also a lot of cross-platform libraries that provide high-quality PRNGS; [OpenSSL is one of them](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rand.html).

Answer (score 3):

`rand()` generates values *sequentially* (in a time-sequence), but does not depend upon time (as in "time of day"), unless you seed the generator with `srand(time(NULL))`. If you don't do this, it's dependent on `1` (one).

There's also `rand_r()` (POSIX) to return the value of the current seed. You could use these to coordinate multiple *streams* of random-numbers, by saving and restoring the appropriate seed values.

For a non-deterministic seed without using `time(NULL)` you'll probably have to resort to a system-specific source (`/dev/random` on unix).

---

At all costs **don't** do this, and proceed to use `myrand()` as a replacement for `rand()`. This will return the same value for each call during each clock second.

```
unsigned myrand() { // BAD! NO!
    srand(time(NULL));  // re-seeding destroys the properties of `rand()`
    return rand();
}
```

If you call `srand()`, it should be *just **once*** at the beginning of the program.

The sequential determinism of `rand()` is actually a very useful property for testing programs. What you get is an (almost-)random, but *repeatable* sequence. If you print out the seed value at the start of the program, you can re-use the same value to produce the same results (like if it doesn't work on that run).